# How to create an Array from other Array?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, dsl

Is there a way for creating an array from other severals arrays, in Objective C?

Comment: do you mean an Array of Arrays or Merging Arrays into one

Answer (score 4):

```
NSArray *arrayC = [arrayA arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:arrayB];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a whole bunch of arrays, you can do this:

```
NSMutableArray * allObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
[allObjects addObjectsFromArray: array1];
[allObjects addObjectsFromArray: array2];
[allObjects addObjectsFromArray: array3];
```

This method prevents creating a new copy of the array each time (which is a side effect of `arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:`).

Alternatively, if you have an array of arrays, and you want to combine them into a single array, you can do:

```
for (NSArray * objects in arrayOfArrays) {
  [allObjects addObjectsFromArray:objects];
}
```

Or:

```
allObjects = [arrayOfArrays valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.self"];
```